# Is it bad practice to have a Jenkins Docker container to handle CI/CD inside the Kubernetes cluster itself?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I've got my K8 cluster which I need to update with new deployments. If I had my jenkins container inside the kluster itself, is this bad practice? The other option is to have a seperate server that ssh's inside my remote K8 cluster and handles new deployments then.

I've looked at this jenkins plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cd/ to handle the CI/CD process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good practice to use CI/CD - good start. I wouldn't say it is a "bad practice" to run Jenkins as a container on Kubernetes - but my experience is that it does not work very well, mostly because Jenkins is not designed for being run as a container on Kubernetes.

There are more modern alternatives, that is designed for containers and Kubernetes. [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/) is the next-gen version of Jenkins that is designed to be run on Kubernetes, see [Serverless Jenkins with Jenkins X](https://medium.com/@jdrawlings/serverless-jenkins-with-jenkins-x-9134cbfe6870) on how it is different from Jenkins.

Jenkins X is [built on-top of Tekton](https://jenkins-x.io/blog/2020/03/11/tekton/), another Kubernetes native CI/CD [project](https://tekton.dev/) and Tekton can be run standalone as well, using [Tekton Pipelines](https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline), [Tekton Triggers](https://github.com/tektoncd/triggers) and [Tekton Dashboard](https://github.com/tektoncd/dashboard). Tekton is a very active community, backed by [Google](https://cloud.google.com/tekton) and Red Hat and more companies to provide a great CI/CD solution designed to work on Kubernetes.